# In mysql how can I get all the data ranges which are passing through any date in a month?

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say, these are sample date ranges-

**from_date  => to_date**

2018-01-01 => 2018-04-01

2018-02-15 => 2018-03-01

2018-02-01 => 2018-02-07

2018-03-01 => 2018-03-05

I want to find the date ranges which has passed through February 2018.

I tried this one. So, I picked a random date from February 2018 and looked for these two condition.

```
select * from enroll 
where 
 (from_date between DATE_FORMAT(DATE("2018-02-01") ,'%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY("2018-02-01"))
 or 
 (to_date between DATE_FORMAT(DATE("2018-02-01") ,'%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY("2018-02-01"))
 or 
 (from_date < DATE_FORMAT(DATE("2018-02-01") ,'%Y-%m-01') and to_date > LAST_DAY("2018-02-01"))
```

1. If from_date to to_date in between first and last date of that month
2. If from_date is less than first date of that month and to_date is greater than last date of that month.

Please let me know if this will work or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Can you add sample data in the form of a table, and also show the output you expect?

Comment: I want to query which date ranges passed through February 2018. In this case bold dates have passed through February 2018. **2018-01-01 to 2018-04-01**, **2018-02-15 to 2018-03-01**, **2018-02-01 to 2018-02-07**, 2018-03-01 to 2018-03-05 @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What data types are from and to date

Comment: **1** "if this will work", try it.  **2** "better way".  Looks good, I had something similar in PHP with a date range similar to this.